# Call a method from multiple thread to populate a data structure and then read that data structure from a single background thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

I have a class in which my `add` method is being called by multiple threads to populate `clientidToTimestampHolder` LinkedBlockingQueue. And then in the same below class, I have a background thread which runs every 30 milliseconds and calls a `processData()` method which drains `clientidToTimestampHolder` to List of Map and then I iterate that List to send data to different service by calling appropriate method.

I can get same userid many times with different timestamp so that is why I am using `LinkedBlockingQueue` with map.

```
public class Handler {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors
      .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  private final LinkedBlockingQueue<Map.Entry<String, Long>> clientidToTimestampHolder =
      new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

  private static class Holder {
    private static final Handler INSTANCE = new Handler();
  }

  public static Handler getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private Handler() {
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        processData();
      }
    }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  }

  // called by multiple threads to populate clientidToTimestampHolder map
  public void add(final String clientid, final Long timestamp) {
    clientidToTimestampHolder.offer(Maps.immutableEntry(clientid, timestamp));
  }

  // called by single background thread every 30 milliseconds
  public void processData() {
    final List<Map.Entry<String, Long>> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    clientidToTimestampHolder.drainTo(entries);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : entries) {
      String clientid = entry.getKey();
      long timestamp = entry.getValue();
      boolean isUpdated = isUpdatedClient(clientid, timestamp);
      if (!isUpdated) {
        updateClient(String.valueOf(clientid));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is my above code thread safe and there is no race condition and I won't miss any data in `processData()` method? Since `add` method will be called from multiple threads and then I have a single background thread which runs every 30 milliseconds to calls `processData()` method which extracts data from `clientidToTimestampHolder` LinkedBlockingQueue.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous classes contain a `this` reference to the outside class (i.e. `Handler`). You've unsafely published the `this` reference before the final field freeze, the threads of the executor may not see the collection properly initialized when it is read.

Other than that, I don't see how `processData` will miss any updates. If the drain operation does not catch a concurrent write, it will not be on the next run. Unless you are worried about this (in which case, you will need to lock), it looks fine to me as long as you do not also modify the collection.

On a side note, what is the purpose of `String#valueOf` on a string?

Comment: Where do you see I have unsafely published the this reference? And how will I fix that? Yeah `String#valueOf` I will fix that.

Comment: The constructor. The regular way to prevent unsafe publication is to use a static factory and start the scheduled task after you've constructed, i.e. `Handler newInstance() { Handler h = new Handler(); h.executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(...); return h; }` and use the factory to create initialize the INSTANCE holder.